# PostgreSQL: How to loop through the xml array

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

How to loop through the xml array. Here is the following code which I tried.

```
for c in select (unnest((xpath('//PayTypes/@value', ('<dummy_root><IncludeSettle/><StartTime value="2019-03-26 08:45:48.780"></StartTime><PayTypes value="1"/><PayTypes value="2"/></dummy_root>')::xml)))::text)
loop
raise notice '%', c;
end loop;
```

I am getting back the following error saying below:

```
ERROR:  loop variable of loop over rows must be a record variable or list of scalar variables
LINE 11: for c in select (unnest((xpath('//PayTypes/@value', ('<dummy...
```

Any help is really appreciated. Output I am expecting is printing values 1, 2.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) ... Question is a bit unclear without example data and expected results..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, you didn't declare the iterator c, I had the same problem with this cause. The code would look like (foo is the table):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION your_method() RETURNS SETOF foo AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
        c xml; 
    BEGIN
        FOR c IN
            SELECT xml_column FROM foo
        LOOP
            raise notice '%', c;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN;
    END
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

    SELECT * FROM your_method();
```